# Mongoose: Nested update Not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have nested array document structure,

```
{
  "projectId": "12345-service-request",
  "projectVersion": [{
    "version":"1",
    "localConfig": [{
      "port": "3003",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "RMQ",
      "logLevel": "2",
      "version": "1.1",
      "created": "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "port": "3004",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "IMQ",
      "logLevel": "1",
      "version": "1.2",
      "created": "07-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "Y"
    }]    
  }]
}
```

Now, Firstly I want to update all the `active` field of `localConfig` to `N` and after that based on the condition make specific `localConfig`  `active` to `Y`.

So for this, I have written following code,

```
let updateActiveField = "projectVersion.$[]."+envQuery+".$[].active";
            let conditions = { "projectId" : "32804-service-request-service" };
            let update = { $set: { [updateActiveField] : "N" }};
            let options = {};
            ProjectConfig.update(conditions, update, options, function(err,result){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                console.log("## Finding new Pbject ##");
                ProjectConfig.findOne({'projectId' : projectId,'projectVersion.version' : version}).exec(function(err,pc){
                   // console.log("## Update new document : "+JSON.stringify(pc));

                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    let projectVersionIndex = -1;
                    let projectVersionObject = {};

                    for(i = 0; i < pc.projectVersion.length ; i++){
                        if(pc.projectVersion[i].version === version){
                            if((pc.projectVersion[i][envQuery])){
                                projectVersionObject = _.filter(pc.projectVersion[i][envQuery], cloudParam);                                    
                                projectVersionIndex = i;
                            }
                        }    
                    }

                    console.log("## projectVersionIndex : "+projectVersionIndex);
                    console.log("## projectVersionObject : "+JSON.stringify(projectVersionObject));

                    let updateActiveField = "projectVersion.$[i]."+envQuery+".$[j].active";
                    let conditions = { "projectId" : "32804-service-request-service" };
                    let update = { $set: { [updateActiveField] : "Y" }};
                    let options = {arrayFilters:[{"i.version": [version] },{ "j.version" : [projectVersionObject[0].version]}]};
                    ProjectConfig.update(conditions, update, options, function(err,result){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Document Updated");                        
                    });
                });    
            })
```

In this code, first update working correctly, but second update not. 
Please provide the correct way to do this.

Current version of MongoDB : `v3.6.6` &  Mongoose : `^5.0.14`

EDIT : Using findOneAndUpdate

```
let updateActiveField = "projectVersion.$[i]."+envQuery+".$[j].active";
                    let conditions = { "projectId" : "32804-service-request-service" };
                    let update = { $set: { [updateActiveField] : "Y" }};
                    let options = {arrayFilters:[{"i.version": [version] },{ "j.version" : [projectVersionObject[0].version]}]};
                    ProjectConfig.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, function(err,result){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Document Updated"); 
                    });
```

Log using mongoose debug true :

```
Mongoose: projectconfigs.findAndModify({ projectId: '32804-service-request-service' }, []
, { '$set': { 'projectVersion.$[i].localConfig.$[j].active': 'Y' } }, { arrayFilters: [ {
 'i.version': [ '1' ] }, { 'j.version': [ '1.1' ] } ], new: false, upsert: false, fields:
 {} })
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, please check updated question